# Problems creating a new screen

Tags: android, user-interface

I am creating a project in which i need to take in some numbers, makes some calculations and then on a new screen create show the answers.  I am using an `Intent` object to go to the new screen:

```
   final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);

   button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
   {
       public void onClick(View v)
       {
           Intent myIntent = new Intent();
           myIntent.setClass(HelloAndroid.this, screen2.class);
           myIntent.putExtra("eFiber", Double.toString(E_fiber));
           startActivity(myIntent); 
       }
   });
```

but when i do this it crashes when i click the button.  If i use the same xml file as i do in the first screen then it works just fine, its when i use a different xml file that i have the problems.

Comment: Did you add the Activity to the Android Manifest File? :/

Comment: You can try using the logcat view (in eclipse) to find out what causes the crash. If the suggested answers didn't help, you can copy the logcat info here (will help a lot...).

Comment: When I run it in debug the logcat view is really large so should I look for a problem in the last lines?  Or should I be looking through the whole log?

Comment: After a crash occurs, you'll find a large "error" part marked red in the logcat view. This should explain what happened. Also, you can clear your log before pressing the button, and then most of the irrelevant staff won't appear...

Answer (score 1):

Have you registered your second `Activity` as an `Activity` in the android-manifest xml?

Under the `<application>` node, something to the effect of:

```
<activity android:name=".my.screen2" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
```

With your specific `Activity` information in place of `".my.screen2"`

Comment: yes i did add that here is what i wrote:

       
 <activity android:name="com.example.helloandroid.screen2"

                  android:label="@string/calculations">

            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category 
android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

i am somewhat unsure of how the intent filter stuff works so is it possible that is screwing it up?